# Getting a 1NF table to 3NF or BCNF

Tags: sql

So I have this table that I guess is on the normal form 1NF, with the primer keys "valutakode" and "valutanavn". What I am struggling with is to get this table from current normal form to 3NF or BCNF if possible.

So I guess I have to split the table into two or more tables, but I don't know what is going in what table. Anyone know?

[image: Image of current table]

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the `Valutanavn` value can be entirely derived from `Valutakode`; that is to say, any given currency code will always have the same corresponding name. Right now the table is violating 3NF because it would allow you to violate this rule, by e.g. having one row with "SEK, Kronor" and another with "SEK, Krona".

To fix this, you could use these two tables:

1. `Valutakode`, `Valutanvn`
2. `Valutakode`, `Dato`, and `Kurs`.